# Lag between data insertion and when are available

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I implemented integration tests with ElasticSearch and Java using an embedded node. Right after having started it up, I inserted a data set for my tests using a bulk request. You can see this link for the used approach: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/implementing-integration-testing-for-elasticsearch-with-java/.

I have to wait a bit (with a Thread.sleep) before actually executing the test. Otherwise the data aren't available and the test fails.

Is it a normal behavior of an embedded ElasticSearch node and can this be updated / configured?

Thanks very much for your help,
Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal.

To make the recently indexed documents available for search, issue a refresh. This ordinarily happens periodically, the length of the period being set by "refresh_interval" (default=1s).

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

Note that refresh does not actually commit the pending data to disk.

It's still a decent approach for your test scenario.

Another is described here:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

For the duration of your testing, set the refresh_interval to -1, saving you the burden of calling refresh. Just be sure to put it back when you are done!